# Rosinstall to install a download pack, something trivial?

Tags: rosinstall, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all.

I am a newbie here, and I have followed up all the beginner and intermediate level tutorials from ROS webpage.

I still don't understand how to use "rosinstall" command to install a third party package downloaded from website say GitHub
(in particular this one: https://github.com/segwayrmp/segway-rmp-ros-pkg.)

Here are the steps I took:
I ran rosinstall `pwd`/segway_rmpX.rosinstall
But it gave me:

"ERROR in rosinstall:
No 'ros' stack detected in candidates [].
Please add the location of a ros distribution to this command."

Anyhow, the purpose of this post is not only to seek solution to my problems encountered above, but more important, could somebody give me a simple guidance I should follow on installing a 3rd party package?

I know this seems to be a trivial question, but I am very confused about installation process. On the website, some even said you don't need to run rosinstall to install a package.

Thank you for your time! CheerS!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62478/rosinstall-to-install-a-download-pack,-something-trivial?/) by [Gazer](https://answers.ros.org/users/4846/gazer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 146 on 2013-05-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here is the [rosinstall documentation](http://www.ros.org/doc/independent/api/rosinstall/html/).

Rosinstall provides a niced [rosws command](http://www.ros.org/doc/independent/api/rosinstall/html/rosws.html) that is convenient for rosbuild workspaces.

For catkin workspaces, wstool provides similar commands (install it from `python-wstool`). See [REP-0133](http://ros.org/reps/rep-0133.html).

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-05-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Gazer](https://answers.ros.org/users/4846/gazer/) on 2013-05-16**:
use rosinstall.